# What is the interval of convergence of the Taylor series $f(x) = \ln(1-x^2)$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, logarithms, power-series, taylor-expansion, divergent-series

What is the interval of convergence of the Taylor series $f(x) = \ln(1-x^2)$ centered at $x = 0$?

For $f(x) = \ln(1-x^2) = \ln(1-x) + \ln(1+x) $    I've found that the nth derivative for $x=0$ is $-(n-1)! + (-1)^{(n+1)}*(n-1)!$

Thus, the Taylor series centered at $x = 0$ is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}(x-0)^n$ =  $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{-(n-1)! + (-1)^{(n+1)}*(n-1)!}{n!}(x)^n$ = $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{-1+ (-1)^{(n+1)}}{n}(x)^n$ = $0-x^2 +0 - \frac{x^4}{4}+\ldots$

Which is equal to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{-1}{2^{2n-1}}(x)^{2n}$, when $n$ is a even number and $=0$ when $n$ is an odd number.

Because of this, we can't apply the ratio test.

Then I tried to see if the series is absolutely convergent by putting it inside modulo. The resulting series is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{2n-1}}(x)^{2n}$

I applied the ratio test here:

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}} $ = $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{x^{2n}}{2^{2n-1}} \frac{2^{2n-3}}{x^{2n+2}} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{4x^2} <1 $ for any value of  $x$. Thus the series is never absolutely convergent.

Because of this, I said that the interval of convergence is $\emptyset$.

Is this alright?

Comment: The MacLaurin series expansion is simply $$\ln(1-x^2)=-\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{x^{2n}}{n}\,$$ hence the interval of convergence remains $|x|<1$ (just as it is for $\ln(1-x)$.

Comment: Can you explain why? @JackLeGrüß. I tried checking on wolfram https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Taylor+Series+of+ln%281-x%5E2%29+about+x%3D0 and I still don't understant why there isn't an $(-1)^n$ inside the series

Comment: We have the well-known MacLaurin series $$\ln\frac{1}{1-x}=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{x^{n}}{n}\,$$ with interval of convergence $|x|<1$. What you are asking is simply the negative of the above function but with $x$ replaced by $x^2$; however, $|x|^2<1$ is equivalent to $|x|<1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since$$\log(1-x)=-x-\frac{x^2}2-\frac{x^3}3-\cdots$$when $|x|<1$ and since $|x|<1\iff|x^2|<1$, you have$$\log(1-x^2)=-x^2-\frac{x^4}2-\frac{x^6}3-\cdots\tag1$$when $|x|<1$. It's easy to see that the series $(1)$ diverges when $|x|>1$ and therefore the radius of convergence is $1$.

Comment: Thank you! So was I wrong in saying that for $f^{(n)}(0)=-(n-1)! + (-1)^{(n+1)}*(n-1)!$ the Taylor Series is equal with $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{-1+ (-1)^{(n+1)}}{n}(x)^n$  = $0-x^2 +0 - \frac{x^4}{4}+\ldots$   = $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n$ where $a_n=\begin{cases}1 & n=2k\\0 & n=2k+1.\end{cases}$? And from here I thought that we can't calculate $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|$. I see now that I was wrong, but I can't figure out where.

Comment: Note that$$-1+(-1)^{n+1}=\begin{cases}-2&\text{ if $n$ is even}\\0&\text{ if $n$ is odd}\end{cases}$$and from this you *do* get the same Taylor series that I got.

Comment: Oh, so I can just ignore the cases when the Taylor series is equal with 0, then? Thank you!